# Did Derrida write a book on the subject of violence?

Tags: derrida

I could have sworn I saw, some years ago, a book on violence by Jacque Derrida.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered with a quick web search.

Answer (score 2):

> In the early 60's, Derrida reads Heidegger and Levinas carefully. Then
> in 1964, Derrida publishes a long two part essay on Levinas, “Violence
> and Metaphysics.”

[SEP Entry on Derrida](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/derrida/#ElaBasArgWorHos)

So yes.

Answer (score 2):

There is this: [Philosophy in a Time of Terror: Dialogues With Jurgen Habermas And Jacques Derrida](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Philosophy-Time-Terror-Dialogues-Habermas-x/dp/0226066665/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1451224396&sr=8-2&keywords=derrida+terrorism).